# org.apache.commons NOT RESOLVED in eclipse

Tags: jsp, import, apache-commons-fileupload

I am using the code to upload File from the computer to the JSP page
I am using Eclipse IDE and Apache Tomcat 7.0

```
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload" %> 
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory"%> 
 <%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.*"%>
```

But is giving error

```
The import org.apache.commons cannot be resolved
```

Can I have to add any external jars to Project ???

Comment: Have you checked this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14609722/the-import-org-apache-commons-cannot-be-resolved-in-eclipse-juno?rq=1)?

Comment: OK !! I added the jar files in Web-inf/ lib folder But still not working  Are you talking about this jars   -----     commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar   and  commons-codec-1.2.jar

Comment: Have you done clean and rebuild the project after added library?

Comment: Yes !! my friend. I refreshed, cleaned and redeployed it but still showing error