# How to fix import error for eclipse with gradle

Tags: java, gradle

This is the first time for me to use gradle.

I just typed gradle init and gradle run (I didn't fix any code)

It worked well.

cmd

```
C:\Users\gksth\eclipse-workspace\myGradle>gradle run

> Task :app:run
Hello World!

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 6s
15 actionable tasks: 15 executed
```

But eclipse pops up a message that "The import org apache cannot be resolved"

App.java

```
package myGradle.app;

import myGradle.list.LinkedList;

import static myGradle.utilities.StringUtils.join;
import static myGradle.utilities.StringUtils.split;
import static myGradle.app.MessageUtils.getMessage;

import org.apache.commons.text.WordUtils;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList tokens;
        tokens = split(getMessage());
        String result = join(tokens);
        System.out.println(WordUtils.capitalize(result));
    }
}
```

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'myGradle.java-application-conventions'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-text'
    implementation project(':utilities')
}

application {
    // Define the main class for the application.
    mainClass = 'myGradle.app.App'
}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14609722/the-import-org-apache-commons-cannot-be-resolved-in-eclipse-juno/26856464 may be this link will be helpful for you

Answer (score 0):

Add this in the **`dependencies`**

```
dependencies {  
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.9'  

}
```

Comment: I did in the build.gradle dependencies.
and the result:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\gksth\eclipse-workspace\myGradle\app\build.gradle' line: 11

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not find method compile() for arguments [{group=org.apache.commons, name=commons-lang3, version=3.9}] on obje
ct of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14609722/the-import-org-apache-commons-cannot-be-resolved-in-eclipse-juno/26856464 try this

Comment: Thanks but.. is this the best? With gradle, should I download jar file and put it in right path myself?

Comment: I think so add dependencies in  Gradle is the best choice instead of adding a manual jar file Because when you send the project then he will also add a manual jar file.